# Añadir elementos a un conjunto conjunto, python

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

tengo un problemilla, respecto al manejo de conjuntos en python, soy novato en este lenguaje. :/

**Este es el codigo fuente:**

```
    conjuntoa=set()
    conjuntob=set()
    conjuntor=set()

    #VALORES DEL CONJUNTO A

    print ("::::::::::CONJUNTO::A::::::::::")

    print("Posicion #1")
    conjuntoa.add(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
    print("Posicion #2")
    conjuntoa.add(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

    #VALORES DEL CONJUNTO A

    print ("::::::::::CONJUNTO::B::::::::::")

    print("Posicion #1")
    conjuntoa.add((input("Ingrese un numero: ")))
    print("Posicion #2")
    conjuntoa.add(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

    conjuntor.add(conjuntoa[1],conjuntob[1])
    conjuntor.add(conjuntoa[2],conjuntob[2])

    print(conjuntor)
```

Lo que me propongo en este codigo es leer dos conjuntos(conjuntoa, conjuntob), y en el conjunto llamado "conjuntor" colocar las relaciones entre ellos:

Por ejemplo:

**A={1,2,3}**

**B={4,5,6}**

**C={(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)}**

El problema es que compila, pero al ejecutarlo, despues de leer los dos conjuntos se cierra y no muesta el resultado (conjuntor), no se si es por errores sintacticos o por otra cosa.

Lei en un foro que se podia agregar dos elementos a la vez, para formar una especie de relacion entre los elementos, no estoy muy seguro de eso.

Necesito que me echen una mano, dandome recomendaciones e informacion que me sea se ayuda, para este "problema". :D

**Nota: ya intente colocando mas codigo despues del "print(conjuntor)" e igualmenta pasa lo mismo.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que los conjuntos [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) en python son una colección **no ordenada** y sin elementos repetidos. Usan una tabla hash por debajo para representar los datos al igual que los diccionarios lo que los hace muy eficientes para ciertas operaciones como las búsquedas.

Puedes ver que un conjunto no mantiene un orden de sus elementos ejecutando:

```
conjunto = set(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'))
print(conjunto)
```

Si ejecutas el código varias veces verás algo curioso al respecto del orden...

Tu problema es que intentas hacer esto `conjuntoa[1]`, es decir, acceder a un conjunto **usando su indice**, al ser estructuras de datos sin orden (sin índice por tanto) esto da un error del tipo:

```
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Para lo que quieres hacer, asociar parejas de dos estructuras de datos según su orden, los conjuntos no sirven, simplemente porque los datos se almacenan sin orden,

Para ello debes usar [`listas`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
listaA=list()
listaB=list()
listaR=list()

#VALORES DE LA LISTA A

print ("::::::::::LISTA::A::::::::::")

print("Posicion #1")
listaA.append(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
print("Posicion #2")
listaA.append(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

#VALORES DE LA LISTA B

print ("::::::::::LISTA::B::::::::::")

print("Posicion #1")
listaB.append((input("Ingrese un numero: ")))
print("Posicion #2")
listaB.append(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

listaR.append((listaA[0],listaB[0]))
listaR.append((listaA[1],listaB[1]))

print(listaR)
```

`listaR` podría ser un conjunto si lo deseas y añadir las tuplas, pero recuerda que no va a mantener el orden de entrada. Para añadir más de un elemnto a la vez se puede usar el método `update()` que admite un iterable:

```
conjuntor = set()
conjuntor.update((listaA[0], listaB[0]))
conjuntor.update((listaA[1], listaB[1]))
```

Recuerda que las listas (o los arrays en otros lenguajes) se **empiezan a numerar desde el 0**, es decir, su primer índice es el 0 y no el 1. Si intentas en este código hacer `listaA[2]` te dará error porque el indice 2 no existe, la lista tiene solo dos elementos y sus indices son 0 y 1.

Por cierto, forma alternativa de hacer lo mismo usando [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) y la función preconstruida [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
#VALORES DE LA LISTA A
print ("::::::::::LISTA::A::::::::::")
listaA = [input("Ingrese un numero: ") for _ in range(2)]

#VALORES DE LA LISTA B
print ("::::::::::LISTA::B::::::::::")
listaB = [input("Ingrese un numero: ") for _ in range(2)]

print(list(zip(listaA, listaB)))
```

Si estas aprendiendo no te preocupes e ignora si quieres por ahora esto. Es solo un ejemplo del potencial de Python... :)

Comment: No te inmaginas cuan agradable es tu respuesta, muchisimas gracias.